# Cannot sudoedit config file due to symbolic links linking to eachother

Tags: server, mysql, configuration

I have been trying to setup a small virtualized dev environment using Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, and am having trouble editing the my.cnf file for MySQL. Running `sudoedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf` returns `sudoedit: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: editing symbolic links is not permitted`. Not a problem, I ran `readlink /etc/mysql/my.cnf` which gave me the location `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`. So I ran `sudoedit /etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, which tells me `sudoedit: /etc/alternatives/my.cnf: editing symbolic links is not permitted`. While reading the link for that file, using `readlink /etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, it points me back to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Is this due to me setting things up improperly? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I think the file that you're actually looking to edit is `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments:

I think the file that you're actually looking to edit is /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

Cheers, Al